# Use MySQL to Find Duplicates and Display on One Line

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to use MySQL to find duplicates and then display those items as one, combined record. For example, I have two columns: Name and Fruit. A sampling of records might look like this:

Joe - Peaches
 
Faye - Bananas 
 
Joe - Starfruit 
 
Sam - Apples

I want to display this data as:

Joe - Peaches, Starfruit
 
Faye - Bananas
 
Sam - Apples

Is that possible? Could you help me with the MySQL query to start? I'm using VB.NET for my application. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` for that.

```
SELECT personName, GROUP_CONCAT(fruitName) fruitList
FROM tableName
GROUP BY personName
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use group_concat here.

```
SELECT name, group_concat(fruit)
FROM table
GROUP BY name
```